# How can i get Celsius/kelvin temperature from a thermal image in python language?

Tags: python, opencv

How can I convert RGB values of the thermal image into Celsius or kelvin temperature in python?

Here is the thermal image taken by a FLIR device:

[image]

Here I am reading image using OpenCV and getting the RGB values from it but I don't know how to convert these RGB values to temperature:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv.imread('D:/Desktop/images/thermal.jpg')
img = cv.resize(img, (300, 300))

for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        print(img[i, j])

cv.imshow('img', img)

cv.waitKey(0) 
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a classic calibration problem.  You need a (R,G,B)->T function.  This is a "surface" in three space.  You need to take some calibration measurements then create a polynomial (easiest) best fit function to your points.

Comment: That is not a pure thermal image. It looks like the thermal colors are superimposed on a greyscale image from a regular camera.

Comment: Ummm, I’m a bit out of my depth but...  contact Flir?

Comment: @CedronDawg what is T function and how to implement it

Comment: @Justme this is a pure FLIR image taken by FLIR camera

Comment: @rizwan Sorry but I don't believe it is a pure thermal image. There are visible details in equal temperature areas, and the FLIR product can superimpose the visible camera image on top of the thermal image, so most likely you have that feature turned on. If it was a pure thermal image, your shoes, black outlines of toes, shirt logo or belt buckle would not be visible.

Comment: @Justme no issue of it is not a real thermal image. We can use any thermal image, the thing we need is just the temperature values in kelvin/celsius from RGB values

Comment: My advice would be to try to get a hold of the app developer to see if they already have that solved.

Comment: Usually Thermal Images are uncolored, I have used one of the FLIR camera and the resulting image was a tiff file, where each pixel corresponds to the temperature value. Is this image out of the box? Or have you applied some kind of coloring on top of it?